# Flutter In App Purchase, check for refund

Tags: android, flutter, in-app-purchase

I have a problem with refunds of my purchases. I query all past purchases when I start the app and check whether a InAppProduct was purchased or not.

```dart
final QueryPurchaseDetailsResponse purchaseResponse =
        await _connection.queryPastPurchases();
```

Now a purchase was refunded, but the purchase is still queried via the **queryPastPurchases()** method. Also the **PurchaseDetails** class does not have any information about the purchase being refunded.

Any idea how to handle this case ?

Information :

- The refund was over 3 days ago
- I use the latest version of the official InApp package
- The purchase was made on an Android phone

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It took me some time and some hints on github. The problem was that i was refunding the purchase but not revoking it. If you click on the refund button it opens a modal. In the modal there is a checkbox for revoking. Click the checkbox before submitting the refund!

Once the refund was made and you forgot to revoke it, it is not possible to revoke it afterwards.

In this case you have the following options :

- contact the support
- revoke it via api ( only possible if the api access was activated before the refund.).

Comment: Do you use consume/completePurchase for non-consumable items? my non-consumable items show up in queryPastPurchases when they are not consumed but is gone after 5 minutes on testing. Can you help me, do we use consume/completePurchase for non-consumables? I need to check if a refund has been made by the user so I can disable the enabled features that is supposedly purchased.

Comment: When they disappear after some minutes of testing, that means you probably didn't "complete" the purchase. Once you deliver the paid content to users, you are supposed to call complete purchase somewhere in you app after you purchase the item.